# Php best way to create easy to read and SEO friendly friendly urls

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I came across many ways to create canonical or friendly urls in php if a project is to be built from core php without using frameworks like laravel or similar.

One approach uses .htaccess. I have an application where I need to make friendly directory structure visible to users. Something like this...

> mysite.com/science/light/level1/easy/questions

What is the best and secure way to achieve this that can be reliable for a website with good amount of content.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like the following. I've used many something like this in many of my projects.

I'd really suggest using [altorouter](http://altorouter.com) as it's pretty easy to use and setup.

If you don't  want to use Altorouter, then you could use some plain PHP + .htacceess.

`RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=page&id=$1`

So that then, the url would be something like this:

`domain.com/[PAGEID]/how-to-make-money-online-at-home`

Comment: For the sake of options on routers I will mention http://www.slimframework.com/